# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Law breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  2         14
Users destroyed                                   2          0
Users contacted                                   3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           399        714
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               74        101
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        317        264
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              130        186
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                74      2,630
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              735      2,219
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          1
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               40          1
Questions protected                              26         35
Questions migrated                               68          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1        246
Questions closed                                521        261
Question flags handled⁴                         154         93
Posts unlocked                                    0         21
Posts undeleted                                   2         29
Posts locked                                      1        115
Posts deleted⁵                                  285      1,278
Posts bumped                                      0      1,193
Escalations to the CM team                        5          0
Comments undeleted                               19          0
Comments flagged                                  3        532
Comments deleted⁶                             1,379      1,061
Comment flags handled                           360        175
Answers flagged                                  52        973
Answer flags handled                            886        139
All comments on a post moved to chat             46          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://law.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...